# Multi-tenant, is this process safe for adding users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, registration

I am building a multi-tenant app.  When a user creates an account they are required to enter an email + password.  Once signed in, that user (the "Admin") can add additional users to their account.  I'd like the ability to add users to be simple - requiring only an email address.  Is the following process safe for adding users?

1. Admin goes to Add User form
2. Admin enters user's email address and clicks submit
3. Email + unique registration_key + registration_expiration gets entered into Users model
4. New user is sent an email with link to registration (like: http://account.myapp.com/registration/o4iwerl23msl424keree)
5. New user opens registration form and enters required password + password_confirmation fields
6. If registration_key in URL matches the one in the DB and it is before the registration expiration, then the user can register

Would you recommend an alternative? If this is safe, how do I get around the required password + password_confirmation fields in steps 2 & 3 of this process?

Comment: what authentication system are you using?

Comment: No authentication system - rolling my own.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott: I edited my question and added step 6.

Comment: I get that you're probably rolling your own to learn but for anyone stumbling across this the best approach is probably to use Devise and the CanCan gem or perhaps a simple bitmask to control user access levels.

Answer (score 2):

Seems reasonable enough to me.

I would add a state column to the User model. When you invite someone their stated would be invited until they've clicked the registration link and done all that stuff.

Then you can set the validations on password (or anything else that is not relevant at this stage) to not apply in this case

```
validates_presence_of :blah, :if => confirmed?

def confirmed?
  state == 'confirmed'
end
```

This might also come in handy if the use wants to see which invited users successfully registered. If your users are going to have lots of states you might want to look at the aasm gem but that would be overkill for this.